# Should ''feelings of love...'' be specific here?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> Why do you want a great family life? Is it because you think it will give
>   you **(-)** feelings of love, intimacy, connection, or warmth?
>
> Do you want to save the world because of **the**
>   feelings of contribution and making a difference you believe this will give you?

Why is the definite article taken in the second example?

The feelings of love and connection that I get being with you are amazing. > Definitely specific and quite different from the second example above

Answer (score 1):

That 'feelings' is specific because of 'of love'.

It is like ' the book of life ' <-- the book is specific <-- 'of life'.

Book about life, The book about life. specific book.

I am lazy to explain further, so I hope this explanation is enough

Comment: Did you read the first example? It contains no article before ''feelings'' so your answer doesn't fit. Knowledge of technology also needs no article but ''The knowledge of technology that Peter used to help me out was sufficient enough to finally get my project done'' is specific now.